# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class convertThis

Tags: php, function, class

When calling the `convertThis` class, error below shows up:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class convertThis in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\xproject_private_functions\convert.php on line 4

Can anyone help me on this?

convert.php

```
<?php

class convertThis
{
 public $err_params;
 public $errurl;
 public $errtype;
 public $errkeyline;
 public static function  errEncoder($err_url, $err_type, $err_keyline)
    {
        $this->errurl= base64_encode($err_url);
        $this->errtype= base64_encode($err_type);
        $this->errkeyline= base64_encode($err_keyline);

        $this->err_params='{:'.hex2bin($err_url.'-'.$err_type.'-'.$err_keyline).':}';

        print $this->err_params;
    }   
}
?>
```

index.php

```
<?

if(file_exists('../_private/_functions/convert.php'))
  {
    require('../_private/_functions/convert.php');
  }
else
  {
        die("Error...file not found!");
  }

$obj= new convertThis();
$obj->errEncoder("http://localhost/af_cbms/index.php?id='36","500","id='36");

?>
```

Comment: looks like you are calling  `require('../_private/_functions/convert.php');` more than once somewhere. try using [require_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php)

Comment: @bansi, Thanks, i'll try that require_once ' convert.php' ;